# JQuery Ajax sends to wrong url

Tags: jquery, ajax

So am trying to send a request to url '/?type=1' like so:

```
a.ajax({
 url: '/?type=1',
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: JSON.stringify(b_)
})
```

Data is sent properly but to base url 127.0.0.1 instead, no matter what url I use. This results in retrieving the entire front page with Ajax.

The General headers read as follows:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:4001/EN/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4001
Referrer Policy: origin
```

Response Headers read:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 4516
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 11:17:27 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 11:17:27 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64)
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-TYPO3-Parsetime: 1551ms
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

Request headers read:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:4001
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:4001
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:4001/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

How can I send the request to the correct url?

Comment: `/` is the root folder of the web server, hence working as intended.

Comment: @Andreas Yes it does. Perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours, it turns out that for some reason, I have to include the complete path in the url. Hence;

```
a.ajax({
 url: window.location.href + '?type=1',
 type: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: JSON.stringify(b_)
})
```

Additionally, I had to remove the slash '/' in front of the '?' to make it work.

Comment: _"Additionally..."_ - That should be the only thing you have to change. `?type=1` is the same as `<current file>?type=1`